# Schmach vs. Schande - Unterschied

Tags: difference

Also, mich interessiert, ob es Unterschiede in der Bedeutung zwischen diesen beiden Wörtern gibt und wenn ja, dann bitte erklärt den Unterschied. Gerne könnt ihr auch ein paar Beispiele geben, wo dieser Unterschied deutlich zu erkennen ist.

Comment: Siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schmach und https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schande

Comment: Hallo Bruno2108 und Herzlich Willkommen auf german.SE! Hast du schon in einem Wörterbuch nachgesehen? Falls ja, was hast du dort gefunden, und inwiefern sind noch Fragen offen? Roland hat dir einen Link zu einem Wörterbuch gepostet, aber es gibt natürlich noch viele andere.

Comment: @Roland: Bitte poste keine Antworten in Kommentaren. Lass solche Kommentare entweder weg oder (und das wäre besser) schreib stattdessen richtige Antworten. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1658/1487 und https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487 und auf https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment den zweiten Punkt unter "When shouldn't I comment?"

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich betrachte den Kommentar von Roland nicht als Antwort, sondern als Material zur Klarstellung, was die Frage ist, im Sinne von Jonathans  Kommentar. Wäre es als Antwort ausreichend, dann wäre schon die Frage off- topic, weil per Wörterbuch beantwortbar.

Answer (score 1):

### die Schmach

Das Substantiv *»die Schmach«* und das dazugehörende Verb *»schmähen«* stammen von Althochdeutsch *»smahi«* (als Substantiv: Kleinigkeit, Geringfügigkeit, als Adjektiv: klein, unbedeutend) bzw. *»smahen«* (klein machen, verächtlich machen, erniedrigen) ab.

Die Schmach war also ursprünglich das, was einen klein und unbedeutend macht. Eng damit verwandt ist auch das Adjektiv *»schmählich«*.

Mittelhochdeutsch gab es auch das aus derselben Wurzel stammende Wort *»smaht«,* welches als Adjektiv *»hungerleidend«* und als Substantiv *»Hunger, Durst«* bedeutete. Das heutige Adjektiv *»schmächtig«* stammt davon ab. Auch das Verb *»verschmachten«* (alte Bedeutung: verhungern, verdursten, später: schwach werden) leitet sich davon ab. Die heutige Bedeutung *»sich stark leidend nach etwas sehnen«* kam erst im 18. Jahrhundert als Bedeutung im übertragenen Sinne auf und ist heute die vorherrschende Bedeutung.

Auch das in Österreich weit verbreitete Wort *»der Schmäh«* (billiger Trick, Schwindelei, Unwahrheit, Scherz, Witz) (siehe [Wikipedia: Wiener Schmäh](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Schm%C3%A4h)) leitet sich (wie vermutlich auch der rotwelsche Begriff *»Schmee«* = Lüge, Witz) aus diesem Wortstamm ab.

Typische Formulierungen:

> Er empfindet das als Schmach.
> Das wurde zu einer Schmach für ihn.
> Sie mussten eine Schmach erleiden, ertragen, erdulden, hinnehmen.
> Er tat ihr eine Schmach an.
> Er bereitete ihr eine Schmach.
> Das ist eine Schmach für sie.
> Die Schmach ist verkraftbar.

---

### die Schande

Dieses Wort geht auf althochdeutsch *»scanta«* zurück, das sehr eng mit *»scama«* (heute: Scham) verwandt ist.

Das Wort *»scanta«* bedeutete: Ein Laster, das jemand hat; oder auch eine Handlung für die man sich schämen sollte. Zugleich hatte dieses Wort auch die Nebenbedeutung *»Beschädigung«.* Daher auch heute noch: »Ein Pferd zuschanden reiten.« Das Adverb *»zuschanden«* (von »zu Schanden«, ein erstarrter Dativ Plural von *Schande*) bedeutete: beschämt werden, enttäuscht werden und wandelte seine Bedeutung im Lauf der Zeit zu: verderben, beschädigen, vernichten. Eine Bedeutungsüberlagerung mit dem althochdeuschen *»scado«* = Schaden liegt hier nahe. Daher hat das Verb *»schänden«* (eigentlich: jemanden in Schande bringen) auch die Nebenbedeutung *»etwas beschädigen«*.

Die Schande ist also das, was Scham verursacht. Etwas, das schändlich ist, ist abscheulich und verursacht Scham. Der Unterschied zur Schmach besteht darin, dass mit der Schmach nicht notwendigerweise Scham einhergehen muss, mit Schande aber sehr wohl. Die Schmach wird einem auch meist von jemand anderem zugefügt und hat eher den Charakter einer Niederlage, während man an der Schande meist selbst schuld ist.

Typische Formulierungen:

> Das ist eine Schande für ihn.
> Das ist keine Schande.
> Sie hat Schande auf sich geladen.
> Man rechnet es ihm nicht als Schande an.
> Du hast Schimpf und Schande über uns gebracht.
> sich von der Schande reinwaschen.
> Die Zeitungen nennen es eine Schande.
> Seine Schuld und Schande wurde ihm bewusst.

Comment: Danke sehr für deine ausführliche Antwort. Das Problem lag daran, dass man in meiner Muttersprache das gleiche Wort für die beiden Wörter verwenden würde aber dank deiner Erklärung ist mir der Unterschied jetzt deutlich klarer. LG Bruno